# Text position in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have an issue when using EditText in my Android application. What I want is a large editable window where the user can start typing after an initial text in the top left corner (typing starts after the text). The issue is that the initial text is not printed in the top of the View.

When using a TextView it look like this, which is what I want:

[image: TextView]

But when changing to an EditText it look like this:

[image: EditText]

What property does set the text position? I've tried to change padding and paddingTop but none of them seem to make any difference. There is also a textAlignment which also does not do what I want.

Update: The properties:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/command_window_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:editable="true"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="Example"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: Can you show us your exisiting attributes code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `android:gravity` should work.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/command_window_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:editable="true"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="Example"
    android:lines="10"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/card"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity="top"

Example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tv_weather_data"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gravity="number"`

In example :

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/simpleEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Please Ebter"
        android:gravity="2"
    />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pgTT.png)